# .htaccess Redirect Ends in Bootloop

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I redirect requests to /index to simply /

`RewriteRule ^/index$ / [R=301,L]`

Is giving me headaches and causing a bootloop?   This is in a new wordpress install.

Any thoughts how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a rule like this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?index/?$ / [L,R=301]
```

Since you've tagged `Wordpress` I must tell you to keep this rule right at top (just below `RewriteEngine On` line).